# How to identify if one personal identifier contains 2 criteria in excel

Tags: excel, criteria

I got some problems with Excel and I'm clueless how to concatenate multiple criteria.

Below I added an overview of my excel sheet (without personal information). The personal information I deleted are mailadresses.

What I am trying to do is to identify the unique mailadresses which both got the statuses 'ENOV_20221104' and 'ENOV_PREREG_20221104'.

The blanks in the excel sheet are mailadresses and the same mailadress can be filled multiple times in the excel sheets. Is there a way to concatenate the information based on the mailadress?

[image: [Excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0Ljl.png)]

I added a column with ' Vooraanmelden' which fills the column with a 1 when the SUBSCRIBE_SOURCE contains'ENOV_PREREG_20221104' and a column 'Aanmelden' which fills the column with a 1 when the SUBSCRIBE_SOURCE contains 'ENOV_PREREG_20221104'. Ideally we find rows where the two columns are both filled with 1 however each row is an entry and an entry only contains one status

Comment: It is not overly clear on what you want to achieve, therefore it  would be useful to show an image of the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

Create a formula to count if the email appears at least once with value `ENOV_20221104` **AND** `ENOV_PREREG_20221104`:

[image]

My formula to FILTER is:

```
=AND(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$35,A2,$B$2:$B$35,"ENOV_20221104")>0,COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$35,A2,$B$2:$B$35,"ENOV_PREREG_20221104")>0)
```

Then create a unique list based on this column. If you have Excel 365 you may benefit from functions like UNIQUE or FILTER, but I got an old version here so I'm doing it with a Pivot Table:

[image]

Just take EMAIL field to rows section and FILTER field to Filter section, and filter by TRUE value. Then you will get your desired output

Answer (score 1):

I have made a solution for a similar problem, creating two columns, one being the adres, and the second one a condition.
I have made a third column, containing all different addresses, and next to it a column, showing the amount of criteria each addresses belongs to, using the weird formula:

```
=NOT(NOT(COUNTIF(C$2:C$15,D2&1))) + NOT(NOT(COUNTIF(C$2:C$15,D2&2)))
```

What's the sense of `NOT(NOT(...))`:

- when the count is larger or equal than one, not becomes `FALSE` (value zero), and again not becomes `TRUE` (value one).
- when the count zero, not becomes `TRUE` (value one), and again not becomes `FALSE` (value zero).

=> this makes it easier to calculate their sum :-)

Oh, the values in the "C" column are a simple `=UNIQUE(A2:A15)`.

Hereby a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try with =COUNTIF(C$2:C$15;D2&1) + COUNTIF(C$2:C$15;D2&2) it also works. No ned for NOT NOT.

Comment: @WeAreOne: the result of a `COUNTIF()` can be 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., while I want it to be 0 or 1. If both conditions are met, the result is 2, which is the whole idea of this approach.